# Ninject dependency injection in SignalR custom authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, ninject, authorize

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application with SignalR and Ninject for dependency injection.
I have a custom authorize attribute for both the web request and the signalr hub request.

I made the following class for the web:

```
public class MyWebAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute // (System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute)
{
    [Inject]
    public IMyService MyService { get; set; } 

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var id = int.Parse((httpContext.Handler as MvcHandler).RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
        if (!MyService.Exists(id)) 
            return false;
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And the following for SignalR:

```
public class MySignalRAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute // (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute)
{
    [Inject]
    public IMyService MyService { get; set; } 

    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(request.QueryString["id"]);
        if (!MyService.Exists(id))
            return false;
        return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
    }
}
```

Ninject bindings in the Startup class:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(kernel);
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().InSingletonScope();
var config = new HubConfiguration();
config.Resolver = resolver;
app.MapSignalR(config);
```

The problem is that the service is not being injected in MySignalRAuthorizeAttribute, though in MyWebAuthorizeAttribute the service is properly being injected.

Any idea what I am missing to get this working?

**Edit:**
Found a way to get it more or less working.

In the startup class I had to add this:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

And then in MySignalRAuthorizeAttribute I could get the service like this:

```
MyService = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IMyService>();
```

This works but I'd still prefer to simply get the service injected with the [Inject] attribute.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: someone able to solve that ? thanks?